# Are the global variables for a package in python can considered as evil?

Tags: python, django, oop, global-variables

For start, sorry for my bad English.

Recently I read book called "elegant objects" by Yegor Bugayenko. One of the  topics in this book is dedicated to using of objects instead of public constants. Author writes that public constants is a pure evil. There are a lot of reasons for this. For example, using of public constants breaks incapsulation - if we want to change this contant we need to know how classes of our package using this constant. If two classes in project are using this constant in its own way we need to change code of this two classes if we change constant.

Author suggests that instead of using global constants we need to create objects and that's allows us to change code only in one place. I will give an example below.

I already read similar topics on stackoverflow, but did not find the answer about best practices or use cases. Is the use of objects better than creating a global variable in some file, for example "settings.py"?

Is this

```
class WWStartDate:

    date_as_string = '01.09.1939'

    def as_timestamp(self):
        # returns date as timestamp

    def as_date_time(self):
        # returns date as datetime object
```

better than this stored in some file inside package conf.py for example:

```
DATE_STRING = '01.09.1939'
```

if we are talking about using this date in several classes of our package?

After reading of this book I decided that objects are much better, but I see a lot of cases when developers of framework or library force us to use global variables. So It is not that simple as I can see. Why, for example, django use this approach? I am talking about file settings.py.

Comment: "If two classes in project are using this constant in its own way we need to change code of this two classes if we change constant." - that doesn't make any sense. Using objects offers no benefits over ordinary named constants in this regard.

Comment: Your question is pretty opinion-based. And there are three types of constants. They can be an attribute of the main (executed) module, of any other module or package or of a class. The first option if very inconvenient when having multiple modules. The other two don't make much of a difference technically. Overall the arguments of the author sound very "javarish" to me, especially the "public".

Comment: I’d like to see an example of the *use* of these values and how they supposedly differ.

Comment: @user2357112 for example if we are using DATE_STRING = '01.09.1939' inside first class as timestamp and inside second class as datetime object, we doing something like datetime.datetime.strptime(DATE_STRING, "SOME_FORMAT") in both classes, but if we change format of DATE_STRING we need to change both our classes.

Comment: This is just silly. If you want an object, why not use the built-in `datetime.datetime` class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman it's just an example.

Comment: This has little to do with constants, really. Constants are usually values you use as is, without really caring about their actual value or trying to parse said value. If you want to have your date string also available as `datetime`, just do `DATE_STRING_AS_DATETIME = ...` for the same effect. Heck, you could even make it a function at module scope, without a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that by creating a class for a constant to offer itself in different forms to different (other) classes you are overengineering your constants. Why does the constant have to know how it's being used? Does `math.pi` know how it is being used? It actually has some methods because it's a `float` object. Nothing specific to the pi constant. Besides, when you do it, you couple the constant to other classes, and when they change their uses you may have to update the constant class. Now that's a bad idea. You want them decoupled. Each class (and only the class) should know what it is doing with the constant.

This is not to say that a wrapping class can't be useful sometimes, specially if you group related constants. But them you can use `Enum`s too.

And globals in a module are only globals in that module. When imported you are either using copies or (qualified) linked names. But even in the linked case if you change the imported value (which you shouldn't because you say it is constant) using qualification, and a different module is importing the same value, it does not see the changes you made. They are using different namespaces. This is not the usual "global variable" concept, when we say globals are evil.